# Shared Cookies between WebView and HTTPClient?

Tags: android, webview, httpclient

An Android app I am building requires web authentication for users to make data calls. In Adobe AIR and later the iPhone, we did this by rendering a login page in a webview-equivalent page and setting a cookie when the user signs in. Subsequent data calls use the same Cookie Jar and so are seen as authenticated.

In the Android version, I authenticate the user using a WebView and then once thats done, I make a data call using DefaultHttpClient, however I cant seem to load the data on the second call.

Is there some cookie gotcha I am missing? I imagine the HTTPClient and WebView would share the same Cookie space. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my code snippet that finally worked (its pseudo code as in parts of it were ripped out of my project and some things like calling MyApplication via a Singleton were more to illustrate what to do rather than how it should be done with best practices):

http://gist.github.com/610754

Comment: Thanks, there are a trillion examples of using the httpclient cookie in webview but strangely almost none for using the webview cookie for the httpclient.

Comment: Thank you very much I would like to vote a million vote for this post ! :)